# When $f \mapsto \lambda\int_{\mu}^{x}f(t)dx$ is contration map

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

$$\Phi\colon C[a,b] \to C[a,b],  f \mapsto \lambda\int_{\mu}^{x}f(t)dt$$
I want to find $\lambda,\mu$ such $\Phi$ is contraction map, so $$|\lambda\int_{\mu}^{x}f(t)dt| < q|f(x)|$$ on $[a,b]$ for some $0 < q < 1$. But i have no ideal what inequalities connect $\int f(t)dt$ and $f(x)$(in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a contraction in the standard $\sup$-norm on $C^0$ then it is easy to see that $\lambda \int f \leq \lambda \max |f| (b-a)$.